# Обернуть заданный тег в тег <label>

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая добавляет тег `label` после заданного тега (`checkbox` или `radio`) и связывает их с помощью атрибута `for`.

```
function checkboxRadioStyling(element) {
    let id;
    let label;

    label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', element.id);

    element.parentNode.insertBefore(label, element.nextSibling);
}
```

Задача переписать эту функцию так, чтобы `input` оборачивался в тег `label`, т.е. чтобы генерился `label`, в него помещался `input` и полученная конструкция заменяла имеющийся в форме 'input'.

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать такое на чистом `js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
function checkboxRadioStyling(element) {
    let id;
    let label;
    label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', element.id);
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(label, element);
    label.appendChild(element);
}
window.onload=function(){
checkboxRadioStyling(document.querySelector("input"));
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А почему `label` именно заменяет `input`  а не создаёт копию? Я привык работать с `jQuery`, поэтому в нативном `js` плаваю...

Comment: Ну если бы создавалась копия, пришлось бы отдельно удалять старую версию, это были бы лишние действия, а так вставить сперва label перед текущим элементом и добавить к нему ребёнка этот же текущий элемент, это фактически тоже самое что написано выше, только меньше действий программно и больше свободы интерпретатору и как следствие процессору)) Вставить в DOM  или удалить с DOM дорогое удовольствие (потому сейчас так популярны библиотеки с виртуальным DOM)